# How to convert a ctypes array of c_uint to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ctypes

I have the following ctypes array:

```
data = (ctypes.c_uint * 100)()
```

And I want to create a numpy array `np_data` containing the integer values from ctypes array data (the ctypes array is obviously populated later with values)

I have seen that there is a ctypes interface in numpy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html) but as far as I understood this is only to get ctypes from a numpy array and not the opposite.

I can obviously traverse `data` and populate `np_data` array items one by one, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient/straightforward way to do achieve this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [[NumPy]: numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(obj, shape=None)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#numpy.ctypeslib.as_array).

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes as ct
> >>> import numpy as np
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> CUIntArr10 = ctypes.c_uint * 10
> >>>
> >>> ui10 = CUIntArr10(*range(10, 0, -1))
> >>>
> >>> [e for e in ui10]  # The ctypes array
> [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
> >>>
> >>> np_arr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(ui10)
> >>> np_arr  # And the np one
> array([10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1], dtype=uint32)
> ```

Didn't get to the specific line of code (nor did I test my assumption), but I have a feeling that the contents copying is done by a single *memcpy* call, which would make it much faster than doing things "manually" from *Python*.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the fastest is to use [`np.frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.17.0/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html). It can be used with every object which implements the buffer-protocol, in particular with ctypes-arrays.

The main advantage of `np.frombuffer` is, that the memory of the ctypes-array isn't copied at all, but shared:

```
data = (ctypes.c_uint * 100)()
arr = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint32)
arr.flags
# ...
# OWNDATA : False
# ...
```

By setting

```
arr.flags.writable = False
```

one can ensure, that the data will be not be changed via numpy-array `arr`.

If copying of data is really necessary, the usual numpy-functionality can be used for `arr`.

---

The in [@CristiFati's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683129/5769463) proposed `np.ctypeslib.as_array` seems to be a better way to create a numpy-array:

- the memory is shared as well - there is no copying involved.
- the right `dtype` is used automatically (which is a great thing: it eliminates errors (as in my original post, where I've used `np.uint` (means 64bit unsigned integer on my machine) instead of `np.uint32`(which also might not be right on some architectures).

Experimental proof of the above:

```
arr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(data)
arr.flags
# ...
# OWNDATA : False
# ...
arr.dtype
# dtype('<u4')
```